# using regular expression to search for * icon

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to use regular expression to search in visual studio code.
The * icon is used to italicize the text block.
eg: *absbcewl*
For some text sequences, the * icon is placed incorrectly (a space between the * and the first word of the italicized sentence). Thus, the search needs to include [a-z].

I can locate instances when using: [*] * [a-z]
However, it includes all cases when it is appropriately used;
Any tips on how to isolate the incorrect cases?

Comment: I assume this is markdown, are you only interested in italicized cases or also bolded (`** Ahgjhg**`) and both bold and italicized(`*** asdasd***`)?  Of course, in markdown a `* some text` has a different function than italics. You would be changing those as well. But maybe you aren't working in markdown. Probably `\w` is a better choice than `[a-z]`.

Comment: If this is a formatting issue with code, have you tried to check if Visual studio code formation can resolve the issue for you? Some IDEs have code formating and will automatically resolve incorrect format issues, even in commenting, I would also check there.

Comment: Yep, it is in markdown. Great, I will try \w

Comment: Great, thanks for your input. I will check IDE

Answer (score 0):

Your second `*` is a repeater for `[*]` just replace it with space and `[*]` can be replaced with `\*`

```
\* [a-z]
```